# How to match anything between * but not match * * *

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regex to match anything between `*`:

```
/\*([^*]*)\*/g
```

It should match this:

```
*text*

*text*

*text text 
text*
```

The match messes up if there are `* * *` in a line:

```
*text*

* * *

*text*

*text text 
text*
```

https://regexr.com/63of6

What's the simplest way to prevent `* * *` from messing up the match? In other words, not matching `* * *`?

Comment: Maybe this? `\*(\w[^*]*)\*`  https://regexr.com/63ofr

Comment: There is too few details here. Depending on what you are doing, you can use all the solutions below, or `/\*(?:\s*\*){2}|\*([^*]*)\*/g` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gYE2QE/1)) or quite a lot of other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match at least a single non whitespace char other than `*` in between.

```
\*[^*]*[^\s*][^*]*\*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IH5PqA/1)

Answer (score 2):

A [capturing regex](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) like ... [/[*\s+]*\*([^*]+)\*/g](https://regex101.com/r/maKxyJ/1) ... executed by [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and an additional [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping does the job ...

```js
const sampleText = `*foo*

* * *

*bar*

 *baz* *biz**buz*

*foo bar 
baz**biz
buz*`;

// [https://regex101.com/r/maKxyJ/1]
const regX = (/[*\s+]*\*([^*]+)\*/g);

console.log(
  [...sampleText.matchAll(regX)].map(([match, capture]) => capture)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `[\* ]*([^*]*)\*` work for you?

https://regex101.com/r/q7kYIQ/1/

https://regexr.com/63ofo